# error: ':' expected but identifier found

Tags: scala, syntax, scala-2.9

Since `type` is a reserved word, I append an underscore when using it as an identifier. (I can find no style recommendation about this.)

```
val type_ = "abc"
```

But then I used it as an argument identifier.

```
def f(id: String, type_: String, typeName: String) = Map(
    "id" -> id,
    "type" -> type_,
    "typeName" -> typeName
)

println(f("a", "simple", "test"))
```

But I get an error

```
error: identifier expected but 'type' found.
def f(type: String) = 1
```

Putting a space between `type_` and `:` fixes it

```
def f(id: String, type_ : String, typeName: String)
```

though this goes against [the recommended Scala style](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#methods).

Is this a bug in the Scala compiler? I haven't been able to find any sort of grammar for Scala syntax, so I can't be sure.

Comment: The guide says underscores "heavily" discouraged. http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

Comment: @som-snytt, thanks. What would you say is the alternative?

Comment: You can always use the reserved word in backticks as an ordinary identifier. `type ``type`` = String`. (Deduplicate the ticks.) The compiler folks use `tpe` and `Typ` or `Type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala the `_` in variable names is specifically used to denote that all of the following characters are part of the variable name up until a white space. So in your case `type_` is a fine variable name, but when you put it in a method signature `type_:` it infers the colon as part of the variable name since there's no white space between the colon and underscore. For more detail you can see page 54 of [Programming Scala](http://books.google.com/books?id=mincYfsQleMC&lpg=PA51&ots=r2a1KNUKf8&dq=scala%20unicode%20variable%20name&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Paraphrased from the book, the reason they did this is so you can do things like `xyz_++=` as a variable or method name since `xyz++=` would be interperepted as the operator `xyz ++=`.

Comment: No, you can't say that about white space.  `def f_%( ) = ???`.  It's worth adding that _ is less of a problem because one uses op chars for methods, where parens usually come before the colon or equals.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `type_:` it thinks that `type_:` is the name of the variable, instead of thinking that `type_` is the variable name and `:` is a separate thing.  Here's a simple example:

```
scala> val x_: = 2
x_:: Int = 2

scala> x_:
res0: Int = 2

scala> x_: + 3
res1: Int = 5
```

Putting the space in there tells the compiler that the `:` is *not* part of the variable name.

So: either keep the space, or dump the underscore.

Comment: Then why doesn't it think that `id:` is the variable name?

Comment: @PaulDraper `id_opchars` where opchars include `=`, `:` etc is a valid identifier. The underscore is required. `x_=` can have special meaning.